# python, while loop, at the start of each hour call method

Tags: python

OK, I have a IRC bot that has been my on going project while I pickup python, and thanks to everyone here who has helped when I have hit a wall.

ok so I have a while loop, I want a way to find if a new hour has started and if so, to run a method to update any settings, and to make sure that it is still connected to channels.  I just have no idea how to go about, checking the time, and then to call a method.

there are many other things happening if this while loop, so doing a sleep for an hour isn't the best way to do this.

As I know questions with out code get marked down, here is some code.

```
while 1:
    if(newhour() == 1):
        run_Method()
```

Comment: _"here is some code"_. I like your style.

Comment: At least, he demonstrated something :)

Comment: The first time I asked a question here, I had no clue what I was doing, and got marked down, because I didn't have any code.

Comment: First time here? Take a tour - http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, you could do something like:

```
current_hour = datetime.now().hour

while 1:
    if(datetime.now().hour != current_hour):
        run_Method()
        current_hour = datetime.now().hour
```

WARNING: This is a very simplistic solution.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use an infinite while loop, you'll  be wasting a processor core just to run a silly while loop. At least put a sleep() inside the while loop if you do use it anyway for a casual test code.

Cron service is already running in the system for this task. Place your script there (or create a script that calls your main script.)

> $ cd /etc/cron.hourly/

Let's say proj_x.sh calls your main script. Create proj_x.sh:

> $ vi proj_x.sh

Place the following code into proj_x.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 
/home/user/path_to_proj_x/cron_hourly.py
```

Make it executable:

> $ chmod +744 proj_x.sh

Now, /home/user/path_to_proj_x/cron_hourly.py is the main script that carries your `run_method()`

Comment: the while loop is waiting for input for a socket connection.  when there is input it looks to see if it matches one of the if statments, and if not will wait for the next input.

Comment: In any case, running a while loop without even a sleep() is not a good solution, until you're writing some very adhoc code. Check the discussion [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119069/cron-vs-sleep-which-is-the-better-one-in-terms-of-efficient-cpu-memory-utiliz)

Comment: I do not understand why I would need a sleep.  the while loop is waits for input from a socket connection, and until then it is waiting, and doesn't do anything.  at times the other thing happening are the keep alive messages. A sleep would mean that I might miss something coming down the connection.

Comment: Ok, I assumed that socket.recv() would be a blocking call and you would run a separate task to perform some action every hour. Sorry should have read the question more closely. @zsquare 's answer is quick to implement and will work fine for your situation.
(Although, you'll still be doing an extra datetime.now() call evertime inside the loop, which you can avoid with a cronjob... depends how much performance you want to extract out of this loop.)

Comment: performance, is one of those things that I have noticed is going down.  but with logging and all the SQL calls, for functions.  getting the time every loop isn't that bad, when I can see how long some SQL calls can take, the waste hit, of getting the time, who cares.